# Expand regex-like notation to multiple literals

Tags: regex, awk, sed, yaml, expansion

I've got a YAML file with nodes such as:

```
group:
  name: test
  permissions:
  - i.can.(create|delete)
```

I need to replace `i.can.(create|delete)` with `i.can.create` and `i.can.delete` (there are many instances).

How can I do this easily?

Comment: So what's the exactly desired output? Each one in a different line?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm too lazy to modify by hand

Comment: But I expect you are not that lazy to not even give a try to some sed commands? What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to create python parser, but no idea how to parse it

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, google for "python yaml" -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML/

Comment: i'm not reinventing wheel :D i just need to replace (this|and|that) parts

Comment: Do you want to do this in YAML, AWK, SED, PERL, Python, or just any Linux command-line tool or scripting language, whatever's easiest? Do you want to do it for all arbitrary regex syntax (that's a very broad question), or only for the very simple example you gave: non-nested parentheses `(create|delete)`? With `[...]` or `['^...]` groups, multiple capture groups, back references, lookahead assertions, ... etc.? Your accepted answer is just a very manual kludge to the simplest possible way of expanding parentheses, not "regex-like notation" per your title.

Comment: [Similar question in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267366/expand-python-regex-to-list-of-all-possible-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to replace all `something(a|b|c|...)` with lines `somethinga` `somethingb` etc.

awk seems to be suited here more than sed:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[(|)]" ; OFS=""} /\(.*\)/ { for (field=2;field<NF;field++) {print $1,$field ;} ; next ; }1'
```

This will do what you wanted

Comment: +1 for a generic solution that works with any number of fields inside `(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.*\bi\.can\.)\((create)\|(delete)\)/\1\2\n\1\3/' file
```

Comment: +1; generalizing to _any 2_ fields inside `(...)` is easy - `sed -r 's/^(.*\bi\.can\.)\(([^)]+)\|([^)]+)\)/\1\2\n\1\3/' file` - but generalizing to a variable number of fields is not an option. OSX users: use `sed -E 's/^(.*[[:<:]]i\.can\.)\(([^)]+)\|([^)]+)\)/\1\2\'$'\n''\1\3/' file`