# Expand Python regex to list of all possible strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, expansion

I am new to Python and not a full time coder as well. I am trying to see if there are any inbuilt regex functions in python that will provide the entire (expanded) list of strings from a python regex.

Example: for the input:

`Good (Morning|afternoon|evening) my (friends|family|brothers|sisters). hope you like (apple|orange|grape) juice`

The outputs should be:

```
Good Morning my friends. hope you like apple juice
Good Morning my friends. hope you like orange juice
Good Morning my friends. hope you like grape juice
Good Morning my family. hope you like apple juice
Good Morning my family. hope you like orange juice
Good Morning my family. hope you like grape juice
Good Morning my brothers. hope you like apple juice
Good Morning my brothers. hope you like orange juice
Good Morning my brothers. hope you like grape juice
Good Morning my sisters. hope you like apple juice
Good Morning my sisters. hope you like orange juice
Good Morning my sisters. hope you like grape juice
Good afternoon my friends. hope you like apple juice
Good afternoon my friends. hope you like orange juice
Good afternoon my friends. hope you like grape juice
Good afternoon my family. hope you like apple juice
Good afternoon my family. hope you like orange juice
Good afternoon my family. hope you like grape juice
Good afternoon my brothers. hope you like apple juice
Good afternoon my brothers. hope you like orange juice
Good afternoon my brothers. hope you like grape juice
Good afternoon my sisters. hope you like apple juice
Good afternoon my sisters. hope you like orange juice
Good afternoon my sisters. hope you like grape juice
Good evening my friends. hope you like apple juice
Good evening my friends. hope you like orange juice
Good evening my friends. hope you like grape juice
Good evening my family. hope you like apple juice
Good evening my family. hope you like orange juice
Good evening my family. hope you like grape juice
Good evening my brothers. hope you like apple juice
Good evening my brothers. hope you like orange juice
Good evening my brothers. hope you like grape juice
Good evening my sisters. hope you like apple juice
Good evening my sisters. hope you like orange juice
Good evening my sisters. hope you like grape juice
```

It doesn't matter in which order it is populated. As long as I have the output in a list, that's ok.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: the OP is clearly asking about Python code that expands a given regex into all possible matching strings. Their example is 100% clear. This is a good and worthy question and should never have been closed. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Related question, but [for awk/sed Linux command-line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764017/expand-regex-like-notation-to-multiple-literals)

Comment: @smci I disagree that it should never have been closed, as the original edit was very hard to understand. However, I feel like the edits you made have the question a much better one. I do not think I have the necessary reputation to vote to reopen unfortunately. At least, the option does not seem to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex). Install with `pip install exrex`.

Then execute in terminal:

```
exrex 'Good (Morning|afternoon|evening) my (friends|family|brothers|sisters)\. hope you like (apple|orange|grape) juice\.'
```

Make sure not to forget the backslashes `\` before the dots `.`, as dots are a special character inside regexes. This will return:

```
Good Morning my friends. hope you like apple juice.
Good Morning my friends. hope you like orange juice.
Good Morning my friends. hope you like grape juice.
Good Morning my family. hope you like apple juice.
Good Morning my family. hope you like orange juice.
Good Morning my family. hope you like grape juice.
Good Morning my brothers. hope you like apple juice.
Good Morning my brothers. hope you like orange juice.
Good Morning my brothers. hope you like grape juice.
Good Morning my sisters. hope you like apple juice.
Good Morning my sisters. hope you like orange juice.
Good Morning my sisters. hope you like grape juice.
Good afternoon my friends. hope you like apple juice.
Good afternoon my friends. hope you like orange juice.
Good afternoon my friends. hope you like grape juice.
Good afternoon my family. hope you like apple juice.
Good afternoon my family. hope you like orange juice.
Good afternoon my family. hope you like grape juice.
Good afternoon my brothers. hope you like apple juice.
Good afternoon my brothers. hope you like orange juice.
Good afternoon my brothers. hope you like grape juice.
Good afternoon my sisters. hope you like apple juice.
Good afternoon my sisters. hope you like orange juice.
Good afternoon my sisters. hope you like grape juice.
Good evening my friends. hope you like apple juice.
Good evening my friends. hope you like orange juice.
Good evening my friends. hope you like grape juice.
Good evening my family. hope you like apple juice.
Good evening my family. hope you like orange juice.
Good evening my family. hope you like grape juice.
Good evening my brothers. hope you like apple juice.
Good evening my brothers. hope you like orange juice.
Good evening my brothers. hope you like grape juice.
Good evening my sisters. hope you like apple juice.
Good evening my sisters. hope you like orange juice.
Good evening my sisters. hope you like grape juice.
```